# renderd apache /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock with reason: Permission denied

Tags: angular

I am working in Angular4 and trying to handle unexpected errors in production.  My scenario is if we get an error just redirect to the login page
Unfortunately Im getting a 'Error: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef...

As soon as I reference Router in the constructor the error occurs.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Code is as follows:

```
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {WSClientService} from '../services/wslib/wsclient.service'
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

@Injectable()
export class VxErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private _router = null
    constructor( private _wsClientService:WSClientService, private router: Router) {}
    handleError(error:any) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot resolve the cyclic dependency, you could try getting the router from the injector.

```
@Injectable()
export class VxErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private _router = null
    constructor( private _wsClientService:WSClientService, private injector: Injector) {}
    handleError(error:any) {
        this.injector.get<Router>(Router).navigateByUrl("/login");
    }
}
```